# Appending a 0 to every value in a column SQL

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012, subquery

I have a database I am currently amending using SQL Server 2012. It seems that all my stored mobile numbers have the 0 missing from them. I already changed the value to float so I could convert the column into accepting only varchars. I tried the following but it left me with a 0 in front but only 5 digits instead of the full 11 needed.

```
UPDATE sampletable
SET Mobile = '07' + substring(Mobile, 7,99)
WHERE charindex('7', Mobile) = 1
```

I have over 30,000 rows like this so it would be too much to manually do this, is there a way I could do this with a straightforward query?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what `Mobile` looks like before and what you want it to look like afterwards?

Comment: An example would be 76684XXXXX became 076684 only, need it to become 076684XXXXX.

Comment: Is the Mobile column defined as varchar or float?  If you converted it to float, you're going to lose your leading zero.

Comment: " I already changed the value to float so I could convert the column into accepting only varchars" - This statement is not clear. Did you convert the column from float to varchar (good) or varchar to float (bad) ? Varchar suits this operation. Did you change it to float by mistake  and you want to correct it now ? If you changed 76884XXXXX into 076884, look for data backup, you lost data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing the first six characters, then simply include them in the `update`:

```
UPDATE sampletable
    SET Mobile = '07' + Mobile
    WHERE charindex('7', Mobile) = 1;
```

EDIT:

I think you are confused by all the sevens.  If you just want to put a `0` before any number that starts with `7`, then do this:

```
update sampletable
    set mobile = '0' + Mobile
    where mobile like '7%';
```

Comment: This executed but did not actually add any 0's to anything

Comment: Is `mobile` being stored as a float or a varchar()?  There are no leading 0's on a float.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE SampleTable
SET Mobile = RIGHT('000000000000' + Mobile, 12)
```

If that doesn't work then it's likely that your "Mobile" columns is a numeric type which strips leading zeros. 
Here's a test just in case:

```
SELECT Mobile = RIGHT('000000000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Mobile), 12)
INTO #TestSampleTable
FROM SampleTable
;

SELECT * FROM #TestSampleTable;
```